# javascript - Grouping elements in array by properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapreduce, underscore.js, javascript-objects

I am trying to filter same color objects from the below json and every color value is containing combination of two values(color and numeric value) but I just want to filter on the basis of color.

Here what i have tried

```
var _ = require('underscore-plus');
var data = [{
"name": "jim",
    "color": "blue 1",
    "age": "22"
}, {
"name": "Sam",
    "color": "blue 2",
    "age": "33"
}, {
"name": "eddie",
    "color": "green 1",
    "age": "77"
},
{
"name": "Dheeraj",
    "color": "blue 3",
    "age": "25"
},
{
"name": "Suraj",
    "color": "green 1",
    "age": "25"
}
];

var result=_.groupBy(data,"color");
console.log(result)
```

Result should be array of Objects having same color.

```
[{ "name": "jim", "color": "blue 1", "age": "22" },
 { "name": "Sam", "color": "blue 2", "age": "33" },
 { "name": "Dheeraj", "color": "blue 3", "age": "25" }]
```

and

```
[{ "name": "Suraj", "color": "green 1", "age": "25" },
 { "name": "eddie", "color": "green 1", "age": "77" }]
```

Comment: filter? grouping? please add the wanted result.

Comment: Result should be array of Objects having same color.

[{
"name": "jim",
    "color": "blue 1",
    "age": "22"
}, {
"name": "Sam",
    "color": "blue 2",
    "age": "33"
},{
"name": "Dheeraj",
    "color": "blue 3",
    "age": "25"
} ]
and [{
"name": "Suraj",
    "color": "green 1",
    "age": "25"
},{
"name": "eddie",
    "color": "green 1",
    "age": "77"
} ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group by the color.

```js
var data = [{ "name": "jim", "color": "blue 1", "age": "22" }, { "name": "Sam", "color": "blue 2", "age": "33" }, { "name": "eddie", "color": "green 1", "age": "77" }, { "name": "Dheeraj", "color": "blue 3", "age": "25" }, { "name": "Suraj", "color": "green 1", "age": "25" }],
    grouped = {},
    colors;

data.forEach(function (a) {
    var group = a.color.match(/^[a-z]+/i);
    grouped[group] = grouped[group] || [];
    grouped[group].push(a);   
});
colors = Object.keys(grouped);
colors.forEach(function (color) {
    console.log(color, grouped[color]);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina Its working as expected, Could you Kindly explain the code.

Comment: basically it gets the letters from the `color` property and use it as key for an obejct. then it checks if the property in `grouped` exists and if not, the assign an empty array to it. later push the actual element of the íterated array to the `grouped` object with the key of the color.

Answer (score 1):

You can group the items using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "jim",
  "color": "blue 1",
  "age": "22"
}, {
  "name": "Sam",
  "color": "blue 2",
  "age": "33"
}, {
  "name": "eddie",
  "color": "green 1",
  "age": "77"
}, {
  "name": "Dheeraj",
  "color": "blue 3",
  "age": "25"
}, {
  "name": "Suraj",
  "color": "green 1",
  "age": "25"
}];

var result = data.reduce(function(grouped, obj) {
  var key = obj.color.split(' ')[0]; // get the color from the key
  grouped[key] = (grouped[key] || []).concat(obj); // use the existing array or create a new array, add the object to it, and assign it to the grouped object
  
  return grouped; // return the grouped object
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this seems to be the half way of the answer.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: OP, in a non conventional way, in order to explain the question further, gave the expected result in a comment to his own question and i guess it takes a little more doing on top of your result.

Comment: @Redu thanks. I've used the `groupBy` definition. If the OP wants, a single array, it's more of a filter. I'll let him decide.

Comment: @Redu Sorry i forgot to add expected result in comment, I have added now.

Comment: @Dori, Kindly explain the code I am new to reduce function.

Comment: @bikkybarnwal - sure I'll add some info about reduce.

Comment: Added a link to [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) at MDN (it explains better then me).  Added comments in the code.

Comment: @Dori, Please help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447041/stream-the-contents-of-each-file-using-web-sockets-and-reactjs

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Jquery.grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) for example

`var result = $.grep(data, function(n){  return n.color == "blue 3" })`

Answer (score 0):

Simply using the `groupBy` function as detailed by underscore docs [here](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy):

```
var result = _.groupBy(data, function(datum) { return datum.color; });
```

You need to provide a function to be used, that will return the attribute to group the elements on, which is color in this case.

If you want to filter instead, as is mentioned in the question, you can use the underscore `filter` method:

```
var blueOne = _.filter(data, function(datum){ return datum.color == 'blue 1'; });
```